# no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.16299 in the manifest list entries

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker.  I have installed docker desktop for windows. I am running Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit Version 1709 OS Build 16299.1747.  I have logged in to docker.  I am running Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b.  I've tried building the cheers2019 demo (from the onboarding tutorial https://hub.docker.com/?overlay=onboarding&step=build) and get the error:

> no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.16299 in the manifest list
>   entries

When i tried executing, docker pull hello-world, I get the same error.

When I run, docker manifest inspect -v library/tomcat:latest | jq .[].Platform, it returns null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is already fixed:)

This worked for me:

Before `docker build -t "yourDockerName"` is executed in bash, in the
Docker Settings/Docker Engine, I switched from experimental false to true

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": true
}
```